# Is there a way to update kernel version without rebooting?

Tags: kernel

I am running an update which can update the kernel to the latest version, After that I am installing a few drivers but they get loaded on the old kernel since. Upon rebooting, those drivers go missing for the new updated version. Is there any way to install the drivers on the new kernel without rebooting?

Answer (score 2):

If the old kernel ist still running, everything is loaded in there. For live patching you would need something like kpatch, ksplice or kgraft, I would say.

And to directly use the new kernel after a 'normal' upgrade via package manager tools you may want to have a look at kexec-tools, which provide tools to replace your kernel without literally rebooting the machine. (All currently running processes will be killed nevertheless.)